# OCR from game scoreboard

Tags: android, laravel, amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract

I want to get scoreboard/leaderboard data from the image of different games like battlefield and rocket league etc.

For that, I used amazon textract API to get scoreboard data from the image.

But Amazon textract API sometimes gives me a wrong result like 7 instead of 0 and sometimes it's not recognized characters from the scoreboard and the result to 90% only not 100%, we need 100% accurate data.

Please let us know if there is any other API or any other related solutions are available to get the 100% DATA. Appreciates

Answer (score 0):

Try http://scoreboard-ocr.com
We have used it for hundreds of different scoreboards